# How to expose more than one file in an npm package?

Tags: javascript, npm, npmjs

I have an npm package. Let's say `example-package`. This is normal way of importing.

`import RootModule from "example-package";`

Now I have one more file nested here.

> Package Root > src > Feature > index.js

Now if I have to import this Feature, I would do this.

```
import Feature from "example-package/src/Feature";
```

What can I do to avoid developers using my npm package from writing long nested paths and they use something like this.

```
import Feature from "example-package/Feature";
```

---

Just to make it clear, `Feature` exports multiple options - `{ A, B ..}` . I do not want to import `Feature` from package and again extract options from `Feature`. Just want to import it with one slash no matter how long the path is!

Comment: Use some sort of automated task to generate the folder from your source before publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution online. Possible solution would be to create a file `/Feature/index.js` in the root folder with following content.

```
module.exports = require('example-package/src/Feature')
```

Now you can access it like this,

```
import Feature from "example-package/Feature";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the feature as an export of your index -

index.js:

```
import Feature from './Feature.js'
export Feature
```

Then anyone using the package can just import like

```
import { Feature } from 'example-package'
```

Comment: That is not what I want. Just to make it clear, `Feature` exports multiple options - `{ A, B ..}` . I do not want to import feature from package and again extract options from `Feature`. Just want to import it with one slash no matter how long the path is.